# Limit prometheus to discover pods in specific namespaces ONLY

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to run Prometheus to ONLY monitor pods in specific namespaces (in openshift cluster).

I am getting "cannot list pods at the cluster scope" - But I have tried to set it to not use ClusterScope (only look in specific namespaces instead)..

I've set:

```
      prometheus.yml: |
        scrape_configs:
        - job_name: prometheus
          static_configs:
          - targets:
            - localhost:9090
        - job_name: kubernetes-pods
          kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - namespaces:
              names:
              - api-mytestns1
              - api-mytestns2
            role: pod
          relabel_configs:
[cut]
```

I get this error - even if I remove the -job_name: kubernetes-pods entirely.. so maybe its something else in prometheus, that needs disabling?

Comment: how did you setup prometheus? point to the docs which you might have followed

Comment: config shown (so its readable now) - I am not allowed to paste the entire file - but the [cut] is just relabel configs etc. - should not be relevant.

Comment: Could you please share your ServiceAccount config for Prometheus? It looks like Prometheus needs more privileges.

Comment: But I cannot give prometheus rights to lookup pods at clusterscope - as I don't have it. I want to run prometheus ONLY for a few namespaces (that I have access to) - and it should not try to lookup pods at clusterscope to do that :(

Comment: So, are you able to share the RBAC config that Prometheus is using in your case?

Comment: @KlavsKlavsen Can you also share the full error message from the logs? "cannot list pods at the cluster scope" looks like the last part of it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that one had to overwrite server.alertmanagers with a complete copy of the settings in charts/prometheus/templates/server-configmap.yaml - to override the hardcoded default in those, to try and scrape cluster-wide.